# Create openssl EC_KEY object based on EC point value

Tags: c++, openssl, pkcs#11

I want to verify ECDSA signature using openssl. The EC point value i retrieve from ECDSA key pair that i generated using PKCS11. Below is the code that currently i have done.

```
VerifyEccData(int hashAlgo,BYTE *data,int dataLen,BYTE *signature,int 
signatureLen,BYTE* curveType,BYTE* ecPoint,int ecPointLen)
{
  const unsigned char * a = (unsigned char *)ecPoint + 2
  EC_KEY *ec = EC_KEY_new();
  int eccGrpSN = OBJ_txt2nid("secp112r1");
  EC_GROUP *ecgroup  = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(eccGrpSN);
  EC_KEY_set_group(ec,ecgroup ); 
  o2i_ECPublicKey(&ec,  &a, ecPointLen-2);
  SHA1(data, dataLen,shaResult);
  ECDSA_verify(0,shaResult, sizeof(shaResult), signature,signatureLen, ec);
}
```

Above code return

> error:10067066:elliptic curve routines:ec_GFp_simple_oct2point:invalid encoding

I'm not sure what is the the meaning if this error. If anyone can help or point me to the right direction really appreciate.

I found this https://www.mail-archive.com/opensc-devel@lists.opensc-project.org/msg08847.html but when i try it give different error.

> error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long

Comment: Please provide the full program source code so the parameters and problematic result values will be clear.

Comment: i update the code @Oleg

Comment: Also see [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography) on the OpenSSL wiki.